# ASTC: Finding exact values of trigonometric functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Our teacher showed us this really dodgy way of finding exact values by drawing up the 4 ASTC (all stations to central diagram) quadrants and making a right angle to the x axis.

So how would I do a question like:

Find the exact value of:

$$\tan(-120)$$

would I go anticlockwise or clockwise, and which angle am I exactly finding?

Comment: You can always look at an unit circle and think that $\sin$ is $y$, $cos$ is $x$ and $\tan$ is $y/x$, where $(x,y)$ are the co-ordinates of the point in question. Now, for an angle of 120 degrees, $y$ in positive, but $x$ is negative, so $\tan$ is negative And the value can be found by a simple diagram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $-\theta$ you should go clockwise from the x axis being the reference.
$tan(-120)$ is the same as $tan(-60)$ and 
$tan(-60)$ = $sin(-60)/cos(-60)$
= $-sin(60)/cos(60)$.
$sin(60)$ = $\sqrt3/2$ and $cos(60)$ = $1/2$ so $tan(-60)$ = $-\sqrt3$

Comment: i'm really confused. If you go clockwise 120 degrees from the x axis. You end up on quadrant 4. The area where tan is positive, doesn't that mean it would not be negative √3, but postive instead?

Comment: @NeilD'souza You can put -120 as well there instead of -60.